# Error in Google Colab while running linear regression model

Tags: python

Getting error while doing linear regression model in Google Colab

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
from sklearn import linear_model 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import os from google.colab import drive
drive.mount("/content/drive", force_remount=True) os.chdir('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Machine Learning/codebasics3') 
df = pd.read_csv("homeprices.csv")
```

area    bedrooms    age price
0   2600    3.0 20  550000
1   3000    4.0 15  565000
2   3200    NaN 18  610000
3   3600    3.0 30  595000
4   4000    5.0 8   760000

```
import math
df.bedrooms.median()
df.bedrooms = df.bedrooms.fillna(df.bedrooms.median())
df
```

area    bedrooms    age price
0   2600    3.0 20  550000
1   3000    4.0 15  565000
2   3200    3.5 18  610000
3   3600    3.0 30  595000
4   4000    5.0 8   760000

```
model = linear_model.LinearRegression()
model.fit(df.drop('price', axis='columns'),df.price)
LinearRegression()
model.predict([[3000,3,0]])
```

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py:451: UserWarning: X does not have valid feature names, but LinearRegression was fitted with feature names
"X does not have valid feature names, but"
array([330999.05823262])

Comment: Trying to understand the question. What is `X`?

Comment: Linear Regression Multiple Variables     **model = linear_model.LinearRegression()
model.fit(df.drop('price', axis='columns'),df.price)**

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a small block of code that we can run to get the same error? A [minimal reproducible example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_reproducible_example)

Comment: import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount("/content/drive", force_remount=True)
os.chdir('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Machine Learning/codebasics3')
df = pd.read_csv("homeprices.csv")
area bedrooms age price
0 2600 3.0 20 550000
1 3000 4.0 15 565000
2 3200 NaN 18 610000
3 3600 3.0 30 595000
4 4000 5.0 8 760000

Comment: import math
df.bedrooms.median()
df.bedrooms = df.bedrooms.fillna(df.bedrooms.median())
df
area bedrooms age price
0 2600 3.0 20 550000
1 3000 4.0 15 565000
2 3200 3.5 18 610000
3 3600 3.0 30 595000
4 4000 5.0 8 760000
model = linear_model.LinearRegression()
model.fit(df.drop('price', axis='columns'),df.price)
LinearRegression()
**model.predict([[3000,3,0]])**
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py:451: UserWarning: X does not have valid feature names, but LinearRegression was fitted with feature names
  "X does not have valid feature names, but"
array([330999])

Comment: I'm going to edit your question to include this, make changes so that it is accurate

Comment: I am looking at the documentation [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.predict) and I'm wondering if `model.predict([[3000,3,0]])` should be a 1D array like `model.predict([3000,3,0])`